# Is there an available open dataset containing the main science fields and disciplines?

Tags: data-request

I am working on an open-science platform where users can write projects about future papers.

When writing a project, they can add tags to it in order to help with its indexation. The related tags will be research fields, topics, and methodologies.

I am looking for a data set to use as a starter with the main scientific disciplines, and I wondered if there is one available. Is it?

Comment: Are you looking for  just a simple long list of scientific disciplines, a 1-column-list that you then curate yourself; or do you want a sophisticated hierarchy of classes of scientific discipines (a hierarchy that is in use by libraries, scince publishers, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found this one and it seems to be a good start: https://figshare.com/articles/Fields_of_Research_FoR_Classification/10305443

Answer (score 0):

Elsevier uses a classification called *All Science Journal Classification* (ASJC), [see the list here](https://www.journalsindexed.com/2016/06/asjc-code-list.html) ([or the archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20201228120955/https://www.journalsindexed.com/2016/06/asjc-code-list.html)).

[This list](https://www.cwts.nl/pdf/nowt_classification_sc.pdf) seems to show Web of Science's classification system.

(And, if you want to have an advanced read on this topic, there are more innovative approaches, such as [this one](https://doi.org/10.1002/asi.22748) used at CWTS Leiden).